# Aria Templates Debug mode non active

Tags: javascript, web-applications, ariatemplates

I'm using aria templates and I'm trying to use the debug mode but it doens't seem to work because I got no log on the console. Here is main index.html.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/aria/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="./view/style.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
</head>
<body>

<div id="output"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        Aria.debug = true;

        Aria.loadTemplate({
            div : "output",
            classpath : "guides.todo_mio.view.Todo",
            moduleCtrl : {
                classpath : "guides.todo_mio.TodoCtrl"
            }
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

any hint?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable `debug` mode before loading the bootstrap or the production version of Aria Templates in order to automatically set the log level for every class to `LEVEL_DEBUG`.

```
<script>Aria = {debug : true}</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/aria/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Another way is to re-set your log level after loading the framework

```
aria.core.Log.setLoggingLevel("*", aria.core.Log.LEVEL_DEBUG);
```

More is available on [ariatemplates.com](http://ariatemplates.com/usermanual/Logging_and_debugging)